# Forcefully change "Entity key" for object in Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

As the title says, I want to forcefully change the ID of a Kind in the datastore is this possible? The kind uses the following for generating the ID automatically:

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
private String id;
```

The reason for this? I accidentally removed some items that I wanna restore, I have their IDs and all their properties, but would like, if possible for the ID to also be the same.

I tried just creating new entities and setting the ID:s but it's not possible it seems. I get no error, but the entity won't be saved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it actually work to manually set the ID of the object.

The reason it didn't work before was because I tried using a custom made ID (just to see if it worked), which doesn't work. If you're using the exact same ID you had before it will work to create a new entity with that ID.